# Формат текста с учетом ширины

Tags: c#

В строке есть меняющиеся значения. Могут меняться от 1 до 4-значных.
Надо сделать так, чтобы изначально было место под эти цифры и строка не скакала вся при увеличении количества цифр.

Вывод сейчас

```
1    остальное значение строки
1234    остальное значение строки(строка сдвинулась)
```

Надо

```
   1    остальное значение строки
1234    остальное значение строки ( строка не сдвинулась)
```

Как отформатировать строку таким образом?

Comment: отформатировать где? для вывода на консоль?

Comment: Строку просто модифицировать. Числовое значение в метод ToString.

Comment: `String.Format("{0,4}    {1}", 1, "остальное значение строки")`

Comment: [padleft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0zk6ydzx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для вывода текста в консоль достаточно задать ширину поля:

```
string s = "some text";
Console.WriteLine( "{0, 10} {1}", 1, s);
Console.WriteLine( "{0, 10} {1}", 1234, s);
```

<kbd>[Тест](http://ideone.com/JEBuRa)</kbd>

Аналогично можно форматировать и саму строку через `string.Format`.